# XMPP: How to query specific rosters presence

Tags: strophe, rosters

Whats is XAMP stanza for get specific(single or multiple) roster presence instead of all ?

I'm using Strophe.js for XAMPP(openfire) communication. As per Openfire didn't provide support for message status(read, received and read) at server side so, I have implemented some extra logic for make it work.

I'm retrieving my rosters by ajax call through querying Openfire db one self and returning rosters, also roster search functionality here. Problem is when I search and get roster through API so I can't get presence of roster. I want presence only for search result rosters instead all users through Strophe.js(XAMP stanza).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a partial solution, it's only working when the roster is online. we can take default user status offline and we can update online presence response.

```
<presence to="JID" type="probe" xmlns="jabber:client"/>
```